# Показать/скрыть объект в Excel

Tags: excel, макросы

Каким кодом можно скрыть/показать `объект Кнопка` в Excel. Есть на `Лист2` 5 объектов, два переключателя  `[Перекл. 4348]` и `[Перекл. 4350]`, и три кнопки `[Кнопка 4354]` `[Кнопка 4355]` `[Кнопка 4356]` которые и нужно показать нажатием на `[Перекл. 4348]` и скрыть по нажатию `[Перекл. 4350]`.

Буду признателен за код для макроса

Comment: Ни каких идей нет?

Answer (score 2):

Все объекты, расположенные на листе хранятся в коллекции `Shapes`, элементы которой имеют свойство `Visible`, управляющее видимостью этих объектов. На обработчик `[Перекл. 4348]` вешайте код

```
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист").Shapes("Кнопка 4354").Visible = False
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист").Shapes("Кнопка 4355").Visible = False
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист").Shapes("Кнопка 4356").Visible = False
```

а на обработчик `[Перекл. 4350]` соответственно

```
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист").Shapes("Кнопка 4354").Visible = True
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист").Shapes("Кнопка 4355").Visible = True
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист").Shapes("Кнопка 4356").Visible = True
```

Только учтите, что в макросе нужно указывать имена кнопок, а не текст на них. Названия можно узнать следующим образом:

```
Sub one()
    Dim j As Shape
    With ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("МойЛист")
        For Each j In .Shapes
            MsgBox "Текст на элементе: " & j.AlternativeText & ", название элемента: " & j.Name
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Вот же ж...:) А я сдуру Hidden применял :)

Answer (score 1):

Если на листе других объектов нет (а кнопки, фигуры, диаграммы - все это объекты), можно без использования переключателей. Нажатие пары клавиш **Ctrl+6** скрывает/показывает объекты листа.

' ---------------

Вариант, если есть и другие объекты.

Разместить все объекты-невидимки на одном общем (назовем его *BigObject*). Красивом, залитом приятным цветом :)

Показывать/скрывать объекты можно с помощью параметра *ZOrder*, т.е. размещая объекты под/над *BigObject*:

на задний план

```
Sub ObjHidden()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes("Кнопка 4354").ZOrder msoSendToBack
        .....' другие объекты
    End With
End Sub
```

на передний план

```
Sub ObjVisible()
   ' то же самое, но ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

Правильнее управлять не видимостью объектов на *BigObject*, а положением самого BigObject относительно присосавшихся к нему паразитов )

```
Sub BigHidden()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("BigObject").ZOrder msoSendToBack
End Sub

Sub BigVisible()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("BigObject").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

И если уж управлять, то пускай он сам собой управляет, нечего ему кнопки нподсовывать.  Дадим ему в помощь одну ячейку и пускай видимостью управляет клик на *BigObject*.

```
Sub HiddenVisibleObj()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("BigObject")
        If Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
            .ZOrder msoBringToFront
            Range("A1").Value = 0
        Else
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
            Range("A1").Value = 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Если считаете, что ячейку выделять - жирно будет, пускай своими средствами обходится, не маленький:

```
Sub HiddenVisibleObj()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("BigObject")
        If .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "" Then
            .ZOrder msoBringToFront
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Все на дно!"
        Else
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```